Normal ordering in perturbations of Lagrangian CFTs (following Polchinski)
I'm unclear on the equivalence of two perspectives on perturbing a CFT: specifically, deforming via changing the action directly, and perturbing via insertion of operators into the path integral. Following Polchinski Chapters 2,3:
Example 1: To derive the energy-momentum tensor of a CFT with explicit Lagrangian formulation (e.g. a free massless boson), the process as I currently understand it is as follows. One couples the theory to a metric in a diffeomorphism-invariant way (often there is more than one way to do this) and then takes the derivative of the action with respect to the metric. So, in Euclidean signature, with Polchinski's convention, we have the following, which holds as an operator equation:
\begin{equation*}
T^{\mu\nu}(x) = -\frac{4\pi}{g^{1/2}}\frac{\delta S[g]}{\delta g_{\mu\nu}(x)}.
\end{equation*}
We can plug into the path integral to show that under a change $\delta g_{\mu\nu}$ in the metric, we have (at least, for bosonic scalars):
\begin{equation*}
\delta\langle \dots \rangle_g = -\frac{1}{4\pi}\int d^dx\ g^{1/2}\, \delta g_{\mu\nu}\langle T^{\mu\nu}(x)\dots \rangle_g
\end{equation*}
where the dots represent arbitrary insertions. In all the examples given of free CFTs in section 2.5, the energy-momentum tensor is normal ordered. While this is obviously necessary to have a well-defined, non-divergent operator in the first place (the second equation doesn't make sense otherwise!), I'm unclear on how this relates to the first equation.
Example 2: In section 3.7, we couple the string theory to a background via the equation:
\begin{equation*}
S_{\sigma} = \frac{1}{4\pi\alpha'}\int_M d^2\sigma\ g^{1/2}\left[\left(g^{\alpha\beta}G_{\mu\nu}(X) + i\epsilon^{\alpha\beta}B_{\mu\nu}(X)\right)\partial_{\alpha}X^{\mu}\partial_{\beta}X^{\nu} + \alpha' R\Phi(X)\right].
\end{equation*}
If I'm interpreting correctly, this seems to be equated to a perturbation of the unperturbed CFT (by which I mean $G_{\mu\nu} = \eta_{\mu\nu}$ and $B_{\mu\nu} = \Phi = 0$) by linear combinations of massless vertex operators, which are normal ordered (as in section 3.6). For example, in the case $G_{\mu\nu}(X) = \eta_{\mu\nu} + s_{\mu\nu}e^{ik\cdot X}$ and $B = \Phi = 0$, the text seems to say that the theory is equivalent to inserting the following vertex operator into the path integral:
\begin{equation*}
1 + \frac{g_c}{\alpha'}\int_M d^2\sigma\ g^{1/2}g^{\alpha\beta}s_{\mu\nu}[\partial_{\alpha}X^{\mu}\partial_{\beta}X^{\nu}e^{ik\cdot X}]_r + \dots.
\end{equation*}
In both of the examples above, we've made an equivalence between pairs of perturbations of a CFT. In showing that these pairs of perturbations are equivalent, I can't see where we would use the normal ordering of the operators involved.
Edit: Is the resolution that it is necessary to renormalise with a metric-dependent term, using a (naively) non-local action? For example, for a single free massless boson, the action is classically:
\begin{equation*}
S_{\text{classical}} = \frac{1}{4\pi\alpha'}\int d^2\sigma\ g^{1/2}g^{\mu\nu}\partial_{\mu}X\partial_{\nu}X
\end{equation*}
so, consider the following (manifestly diffeomorphism-invariant) action:
\begin{align*}
S = \frac{1}{4\pi\alpha'}\int d^d\sigma\ g^{1/2}(\sigma) \left(\int d^d\sigma'\ g^{1/2}(\sigma')(\partial^{\mu}X(\sigma)\partial_{\mu}'X(\sigma') + \alpha' \partial^{\mu}\partial'_{\mu}\ln d(\sigma,\sigma')) \right. \\
\left. \times \left(\frac{\eta^{1-d}}{\Omega_{d-1}}\delta(d(\sigma,\sigma')-\eta)\right) - \frac{\alpha'}{6\epsilon}R + \mathcal{O}(\alpha'^2)\right)
\end{align*}
where $\epsilon$ is a dimensional regulator and $\eta$ is a different point-splitting regulator (not that this regularisation scheme should be unique). Here we contracted indices by parallel transport along the geodesic connecting $\sigma$ and $\sigma'$, and $d(\sigma,\sigma')$ is the geodesic distance from $\sigma$ to $\sigma'$. This is then consistent with the definition of $T_{\mu\nu}$ in terms of the variation of the path integral in the first example, and the intuition seems to carry over to the second example too.
Would additionally be grateful for any reference suggestions on this topic.
